# Suppress output from Import-PSSession

Tags: powershell

How do you avoid all of the unwanted console output when doing `Import-PSSession`? I'm writing a script to monitor some stuff in Exchange and it needs to drop into our monitoring system and only produce very specific output, but whenever I import my Exchange session it produce

> WARNING: Some imported command names include unapproved verbs which
>   might make them less discoverable.  Use the Verbose parameter for more
>   detail or type Get-Verb to see the list of approved verbs.

I've tried:

```
$Session=(Import-PSSession(New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange \
 -ConnectionUri http://CasServer/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos           \
 -Credential $Cred -AllowClobber -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue)
```

It still displays the unwanted text. I've also tried `-ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue`; doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following switch to suppress the warning, if specifying all the cmdlets you want to use isn't feasible:

```
-DisableNameChecking
```

Example:

```
Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking
```

Answer (score 4):

I think better solution is to read the output of the `Import-PSSession` into variable such as:

```
$output = Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber
```

Then you can read the `$output` and see if it is a warning, error etc.

But don't use `-WarningAction:SilentlyContinue` or `-ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue` because you'll never see if it is oK or not

Answer (score 3):

You are setting -WarningAction on Import-PSSession. Warning you get smells like Import-Module (that Import-PSSession calls behind the scenes).

You may change $WarningPreference global variable to SilentlyContinue for the life of your script. That would silent the warning you get.

Answer (score 0):

you can try pipe to `| out null`

Comment: Just adding out-null didn't work --

What did work is that + explicitly importing the commands I want:

    Import-PSSession $Session -CommandName Get-MailboxDatabase, Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus

Comment: Good, you can asnswer your question, will be a good info for other users!

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
Import-PSSession $session 3> $null
```